# md-nav-bar not working even md radio and date picker working in same page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to make md navbar using angular material, but its not working, Also I have tried md radio and datepicker on same page those working proper but nav bar is not working.I have take code form this https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.5/demo/navBar

My HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.css">

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <md-content>
      <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <h4>Disabled date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" placeholder="Enter date" disabled></md-datepicker>
      <h4>Date-picker with min date and max date</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" placeholder="Enter date"
       md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>

       <md-radio-group>
  <md-radio-button value="1">Option 1</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="2">Option 2</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
    </md-content>




   <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak>
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar
      md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem"
      nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">
        Page One
      </md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page2')" name="page2">
        Page Two
      </md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page3')" name="page3">
        Page Three
      </md-nav-item>
      <!-- these require actual routing with ui-router or ng-route, so they
      won't work in the demo
      <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#page4" name="page5">Page Four</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="app.page5" name="page4">Page Five</md-nav-item>
      You can also add options for the <code>ui-sref-opts</code> attribute.
      <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="page6" sref-opts="{reload:true, notify:true}">
        Page Six
      </md-nav-item>
      -->
    </md-nav-bar>
    <div class="ext-content">
      External content for `<span>{{currentNavItem}}</span>`.
    </div>

    <md-checkbox ng-model="disableInkBar">Disable Ink Bar</md-checkbox>

  </md-content>
</div>




  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My js

```
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();
  $scope.minDate = new Date(
    $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
    $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
    $scope.myDate.getDate());
  $scope.maxDate = new Date(
    $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
    $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
    $scope.myDate.getDate());



(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('navBarDemoBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

  function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';
  }
})();



});
```

Can you guys help me in creating md navbar from the angular material?

Comment: Can you create a plnkr/jsfiddle [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your app and the problem?

Comment: Okay, Here is my Code, plz check https://jsfiddle.net/shubhamshri/90bygnr4/8/